# Syncing between Mac OS X and iPhone

Tags: iphone

Is there any progress made in this area since this post in 2008?

[How do I sync application data between an iPhone and another computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185673/how-do-i-sync-application-data-between-an-iphone-and-another-computer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out Marcus Zarra's new open source sync library, [ZSync](http://www.zarrastudios.com/ZSync/ZSync.html).