# iPhone: Get data off

Tags: iphone, sqlite, export

Newbie Q.

I am building an app that will store data in sqLite then will collect it at week's end when the staff comes into the office.

What options do I have to get the data off.

Perhaps a receiving REST Web service?

Is there an 'export to iTunes file system' or something like that other option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on the amount and type of information.

For a lot of data that needs to go to a central place, then a webservice is probably the easiest to use for machine processing.

For a lot of data that needs to go onto the users computer, then a client-server structure using Bonjour networking where they run a server on their computer may be best.

For simple data that is not going to be machine processed and instead is simply a report for humans to read, I like to use the Mail API to allow the user to email the results to themselves or anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Having it upload data to a web service is the typical way to accomplish this.

Apple did not provide any APIs for interacting with the iTunes Sync system.

Answer (score 1):

While iTunes backs up your data, there is no official way to access the data in these backups (AFAIK).

Instead of posting to a web service, you could also serve the data from your app, and have a desktop client download it from the phone.

In both cases, you could use Bonjour to publish the address.

Answer (score 1):

Also see this question for the sync to desktop scenario: [Syncing between Mac OS X and iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956225/syncing-between-mac-os-x-and-iphone)

It seems kind of ridiculous that apple doesn't have support for sync services on the iPhone yet.

Comment: If they support sync, they have to worry about access to the data (and the security hole that exposes).  Now, they are down the pipe with all these apps, what happens if they open this pipe?  (Note: this is very tongue in cheek)